# My console is bugged in python 3.0

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a issue with python 3.0, I'm working on Liclipse and my console is not live updated when I call a print function. It's pretty weird because once the windows is closed, every messages are displayed in the console. It's working fine in 2.7

Here is a sample code (adapted to 2.7) :

```
from Tkinter import *
import random 

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",  command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="left")
        hi_there = Button(self, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        hi_there.pack(side="left")
    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

in 3.0 my console is not live updated with the "hi, there, everyone!" messages.

Edit : Even the error messages in console aren't displayed when they re supposed to be, everything happens once the program is closed. I feel like the issue is related to LiClipse but it bugs me since it works perfectly in 2.7

Comment: Sounds like an event loop problem... Your messages are queued up until you stop the running thread

Comment: Yea seems like my messages are queued somewhere... but why is it working fine in 2.7? How can I improve this sample code then?

Comment: I'm not sure all the differences between python3 and 2, but I've never seen that issue before, so I don't know what you could do differently

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. Your program works under both Python versions you mentioned

Comment: Your console is updated for every time you press the "Hello" button? mine is not (in 3.0). It is only displayed once I close the program

Comment: I have solved my issue by creating a new workspace... I have no idea what was going on.